# Selecting image sections in R GUI?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write an R function that allows a user to select a rectangle within a displayed image. The selection could then be used for zooming, copying or other manipulation. The gwidgets package appears to provide this functionality for many of its widgets, but not for images. Does anyone have a suggestion for where to turn next?

Thanks!

Comment: The `zoom` package already has this functionality - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoom/index.html

Comment: As far as I can tell the zoom package does what it says - that is it's all about zooming. On the other hand I have realised that an image can be drawn as a plot(), which at least gives basic region selection. But I was hoping for something that would allow a selection to be not just made, but adjusted, and then used in various ways. It looks like gtkimageview might be what I am after - although there do not seem to be any R bindings. Maybe it wouldn't be too difficult to write them?

Comment: I think you can do this with the tcltk and tcltk2 packages, but you have build your own GUI in R and convert your image to gif (not jpg) or png (starting tcltk 8.6) to display it in a label and implement some actions bound to mouse events (click-drag...). For an GUI programming introduction into tk (the GUI part of tcl/tk) see e. g. http://www.sciviews.org/recipes/tcltk/toc/